# Wordpress Simple facebook connect - Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress

I am using [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) for Worpress.

However I am getting some javascript errors.[image: Javascript Errors]
[View Image Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afFIg.png)

> www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php?api_key=xxxx&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fjquery.webspirited.com%2F%3Fxd_receiver%3D1&id=189373481094312&name=&width=285&connections=10&stream=0&logobar=1&css=
>   GET (same url as above) undefined (undefined) Unsafe
>
> JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://jquery.webspirited.com/ from frame with URL
>   http://www.facebook.com/extern/login_status.php?api_key=xxxx&extern=2&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fjquery.webspirited.com%2F%3Fxd_receiver%3D1&locale=en_US.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must
>   match.

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. This error happens in Safari and sometimes Chrome. The webkit based browsers have a somewhat tighter security model for cross domain same-origin policies. The way Facebook Connect works is that it tries one method to make things work, then if that fails, it falls back to another approach.

The fall back means that the code still works, but the error comes up because they try that method first.

This is how Facebook's code works. You can't fix it. You can't work around it. If you're going to use Facebook's code, then you learn to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

last time, when i got an error like this, i forgot to set up the url in my facebook-application.

http://www.facebook.com/developers/ > Application settings > Web Site > Site URL, Site Domain

The api-key is alway linked with your url. The url of the website, where u implement the iframe must have the same URL like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might like my Simple Facebook Comments For Wordpress wordpress plugin I recently released.  It makes the whole process of adding facebook connect comments to your wordpress site super easy and fast.

http://www.davidswordpressplugins.com/simple-facebook-comments-for-wordpress/